# Can I access the sent Email folder using SmtpClient and delete the sent email?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using `SmtpClient` to send email with attachment.

Can I delete the sent email from sent folder using `SmtpClient` ?

Here is my code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

using var mailMessage = new MailMessage();

mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(s));
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("mohammad.jouhari@gmail.com");
mailMessage.Subject = "Remote Freelance Web Developer,Mohammad Jouhari Latest CV";
mailMessage.Body = "Dear Hiring Manager,\r\n\r\n Please find attached CV.\r\n\r\n " +
                        "My work sample:https://github.com/mohammadjouhari.\r\n\r\n" +
                        "My linkedin Profile: https://www.linkedin.com/in/mohammad-jouhari-42461330/";

string pdfFilePath = "C:\\Users\\m_243\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\microsoft documentation\\.net core\\SendEmailTest" +
                        "\\SendEmailTest\\wwwroot\\MohammadJouhariCV.pdf";
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFilePath);

var attachment = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "MohammadJouhariCV.PDF");
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);

NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("mohammad.jouhari@gmail.com", ""); // password for connection smtp if you don't have have then pass blank

SmtpClient _smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
_smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
_smtpClient.Port = 587;
_smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
_smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
_smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
_smtpClient.Credentials = loginInfo;
_smtpClient.Send(mailMessage); // _smtpClient will be disposed by container
_smtpClient.Dispose();
```

I was trying this code

```
Pop3Client pop3 = new Pop3Client();
pop3.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
pop3.Username = "mohammad.jouhari@gmail.com";
pop3.Password = "";
pop3.Port = 587;
pop3.EnableSsl = true;

pop3.Connect();
pop3.DeleteAllMessages();
pop3.Dispose();
```

I am getting an error in  `pop3.Connect();`

> Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received

Comment: No. That's a platform-specific api, the way to do this in Gmail will be different to Outlook. For example, Microsoft uses their Graph api to manage mailboxes. It also looks like you're planning on writing code to send your CV in bulk to a list of recruiters. Trust me, when we read CVs like this we can tell that the applicant hasn't made an effort to learn about the company. At a minimum, I would expect to see the applicant name the company and relate their work experience to what the company produces

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson, I  was doing and I stopped, Any ways, can I use POP3 pop3.DeleteAllMessages(); Spire.Email.Pop3;

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson can you please post, your comment as answer and i willl accept it, thanks

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson should I close the question ?

Comment: No need - you've accepted an answer. Even if the answer is "No", it still might help another developer with the same question in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The POP3 `DELE` command deletes from the inbox, not the outbox. Deleting emails from other mailboxes is done through a platform-specific api - the way to do this in Gmail will be different to Outlook. For example, Microsoft uses their Graph api to manage mailboxes. Google calls them 'labels' instead of 'mailboxes' and an email can have more than one label associated with it